# Is there a way to make an Ubuntu service refresh automatically?

Tags: python, flask

I'm running a Flask API on an Ubuntu 20.04 server. The API pulls data from a pickled file. I've noticed that you have to restart the service for the Flask app to update with the new data from the file. Is there a way to have it pull from the file every time it receives a request?

Answer (score -1):

What you want is to move your pickle loading code to a decorator, and then decorate the functions that need the fresh pickle with that decorator.

[There's](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) a lot [of information](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-in-python/) to be found on [decorators](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-decorators-in-python-by-example-b398328163b), but here's a small example:

```py
def preload(func):
    def preload_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("put your pickle load code here.")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return preload_wrapper


@preload
def im_a_http_get_function():
    print("you can see the order in which this gets executed")


# call the funciton for testing
im_a_http_get_function()
```

**output**

```
put your pickle load code here.
you can see the order in which this gets executed
```